# How to read all the files in a folder using R and create objects with the same file names?

Tags: r, function, object, assign, read.table

I need to create a function in R that reads all the files in a folder (let's assume that all files are tables in tab delimited format) and create objects with same names in global environment. I did something similar to this (see code below); I was able to write a function that reads all the files in the folder, makes some changes in the first column of each file and writes it back in to the folder. But the I couldn't find how to assign the read files in to an object that will stay in the global environment.

```
changeCol1 <- function () {
     filesInfolder <- list.files()
     for (i in 1:length(filesInfolder)){
         wrkngFile <- read.table(filesInfolder[i])
         wrkngFile[,1] <- gsub(0,1,wrkngFile[,1])
         write.table(wrkngFile, file = filesInfolder[i], quote = F, sep = "\t")
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your loop after making the changes:

```
assign(filesInfolder[i], wrkngFile, envir=globalenv())
```

If you want to put them into a list, one way would be, outside your loop, declare a list:

```
mylist = list()
```

Then, within your loop, do like so:

```
mylist[[filesInfolder[i] = wrkngFile]]
```

And then you can access each object by looking at:

```
mylist[[filename]]
```

from the global env.

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: By the way -- just because you _can_ do this, doesn't mean you _should_... the better way to do it is probably to put these variables into a list, as @hrbrmstr states. I was just answering your question exactly as you posed it.

Answer (score 3):

You are much better off assigning them all to elements of a named `list` (and it's pretty easy to do, too):

```
changeCol1 <- function () {
  filesInfolder <- list.files()
  lapply(filesInfolder, function(fname) {
    wrkngFile <- read.table(fname)
    wrkngFile[,1] <- gsub(0, 1, wrkngFile[,1])
    write.table(wrkngFile, file=fname, quote=FALSE, sep="\t")
    wrkngFile
  }) -> data
  names(data) <- filesInfolder
  data
}

a_list_full_of_data <- changeCol1()
```

Also, `F` will come back to haunt you some day (it's not protected where `FALSE` and `TRUE` are).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about T and F.  I was using as T and F all these days and never thought that it will be a problem sometime.